# delete all survery responses via content and structure (can't find the list)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, survey

I would like to delete all responses of a survey. I have tried using the  Content and Structure but I can't see to find the site and the list using Content and Structure.

The sites are created with managed path like so /sites/ and /teams and I can't see to find the sites through content and structure.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't find surveys under Content & Structure  then other ways  append this _layouts/sitemanager.aspx into your site collection URL like this

```
http://Your-Site/_layouts/sitemanager.aspx
```

Now you can delete all responses here. check this [How to Remove All Responses from SharePoint](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2010/06/how-to-remove-all-responses-from-sharepoint-survey.html#ixzz4F0mGOGHM) Survey

Comment: Thanks Waqas that worked. I was only appending it to the root site

Comment: Great, if that worked then please mark this as answer for everyone benefits.